# Proving $(\sin x)^{\sin x}<\cos x$ for $0<x\leq\frac{2\pi}{9}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, proof-explanation

> Prove that $$(\sin x)^{\sin x}<\cos x$$
>   for $0<x\leq\frac{2\pi}{9}$.

My try was to do $\sin x\log\sin x-\log\cos x<0$ So I did $f(x)=\sin x\log\sin x-\log\cos x$ and $f'(x)=\cos x\log\sin x+\cos x+\cot x$, but I don't know what to do now.

Comment: My try was to do $\sin x\log\sin x-\log\cos x<0$ So I did $f(x)=\sin x\log \sin x-\log\cos x$ and $f'(x)=\cos x\log \sin x+\cos x+\cotan x$, but I don't know what to do now.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Please add the text of your comment to the question itself. Not everybody reads the comments and, otherwise, your question risks being down-voted and/or closed.

Comment: The derivative of $-\log\cos x$ is $\tan x$, not $\cot x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show $F(x)=\log(\cos(x))-\log(\sin(x)^{\sin(x)})$ is non-negative on the given interval $I$. Note $F(2\pi/9)\approx 0.0175591>0$ and we can continuously extend $F$ from the right at $0$ to $F(0)=0$. To show $F$ is non-negative, we'll show it is concave down. We have
$$
F''(x)=-\sec ^2(x)-\cos (x) \cot (x)+\sin (x) (1+\log (\sin (x)))
$$Now we use the fact that $\sin(x)\log(\sin(x))<0$ on $I$. Then
$$
F''(x)<-\sec ^2(x)-\cos (x) \cot (x)+\sin (x)\cdot 1
$$We can multiply this by $\sin(x)$ without changing the sign:
$$
(-\sec ^2(x)-\cos (x) \cot (x)+\sin (x))\cdot\sin(x) = -\tan (x) \sec (x)-\cos (2 x)<0
$$Then $F''(x)<0$ on $I$, so $F(x)>0$ on $I$.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer; just made for the fun of it !*

Considering the function
$$f(x)=\log (\cos (x))-\sin (x) \log (\sin (x))$$ expand it composing Taylor series built at $x=0$ and consider the truncet
$$f(x)=-x \log (x)-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$$
Consider the function
$$g(x)=-x \log (x)-\frac{x^2}{2}$$

The maximum of $g(x)$ is attained at
$$x_*=W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\approx 0.278465  $$ ($W(.)$ being Lambert function) while an "exact" calculation for $f(x)$ reveals a maximum $x\approx 0.277208$
$$g(x_*) =\frac{1}{2} W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right) \left(2+W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\right)\approx 0.317236$$ while the maximum value of $f(x)$ is 
$\approx 0.315706$.

Similarly, the solution of $g(x)=0$ corresponds to
$$x=2 W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\approx 0.703467$$ which is not far from $0.711828$  solution of $f(x)=0$ (notice that these nmbers are $ \gt \frac{2\pi}9=0.698132$